# ajax пропадает часть страницы

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

Есть страница, на ней расположен калькулятор(все просчеты расположены в .js, там же прикручен ajax)

После нажатия на блок, отвечающий за выбор категории, происходит выполнение скрипта и блоки, расположенные на странице до калькулятора, остаются, а блоки под калькулятором пропадают.
То есть при обновлении обновлении/первоначальном заходе на страницу всё отображается корректно, после выбора категории div'ы, расположенные под калькулятором, пропадают.
Вариант с вприсывание div'ов в скрипт не подходит, в связи с большим количеством страниц.

Вот начало скрипта до div'ов с калькулятором:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.accordion .submenu a').click(function(e) {
        if($(this).parent().is('open')) {
            $(this).parent().removeClass('open');   
            $(this).parent().find('.submenu').height(0)
        } else { 
            $(this).parent().find('.submenu').height($(this).parent().find('.submenu a').height()*$(this).parent().find('.submenu a').length);
            $(this).parent().addClass('open');
        }
    });  

    $(function() {
    var Accordion = function(el, multiple) {
        this.el = el || {};
        this.multiple = multiple || false;

        // Variables privadas
        var links = this.el.find('.link');
        // Evento
        links.on('click', {el: this.el, multiple: this.multiple}, this.dropdown)
    }

    Accordion.prototype.dropdown = function(e) {
        var $el = e.data.el;
            $this = $(this),
            $next = $this.next();

        $next.slideToggle();
        $this.parent().toggleClass('open');

        if (!e.data.multiple) {
            $el.find('.submenu').not($next).slideUp().parent().removeClass('open');
        };
    }   
    function select()

}


    var accordion = new Accordion($('#accordion'), false);
});


    $('.accordion .submenu a').click(function(e) {
        $('.accordion .submenu a').removeClass('open');
        $(this).addClass('open');

 $('.small-content').html(
    '<div id="layer1"><div class="form eda"><div class="title"><span class="black" style="font-size: 12px;">КАЛЬКУЛЯТОР '+$(this).html()+'</span></div></div></div>'+
    .... Тут расположены блоки калькулятора .....
```

Конец калькулятора:

```
'<a class="btn"><span style="margin-left: 18px; margin-right: 20px;">CONFIRM</span></a>'+
    );
    return false;       
});
```

Далее есть вот такое:

```
$('.eda').click(function(){
$('.eda').ready(function(){
    $('.form').addClass('divruoff')
});
});
```

Необходимо, чтобы скрипт обрабатывал только определенную часть кода, а не всю страницу.

Comment: Чтобы Вам чем-то помочь - нужен код :) Кусок кода, где вызывается калькулятор, js, обрабатывающий запрос нажатия на блок

Comment: Покажите также код, самих блоков до и после калькулятора, и собственно сам калькулятор, потому что требуется также посмотреть как Вы вызываете скрипт.

Comment: @Legionary Добавила. Надеюсь то, что нужно

Comment: Возможно я ошибаюсь, но не пойму что проверяет следующий код:

if($(this).parent().is('open'))

Вы пытаетесь проверить существование класса у родителя?...

Если да - то не факт что сработает. Лучше проверять через hasClass()

Comment: вы в  if($(this).parent().is('open')) забыли указать точку, обозначающую класс.  if($(this).parent().is('.open'))

Comment: Автор сия творения не я, а "добросовестный фрилансер", поэтому мне, как человеку ничего не понимающему в подобном, пришлось методом тыка удалять и восстанавливать строчки.
 $('.small-content').html( - сие добро просто надо было снести и заменить пару строк. 
Спасибо откликнувшимся!